# Remove specific values from numpy array under certain conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this :

```
answer = [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0...,1, 1, 0,] # of size m
```

each entry of answer is a digit between 0 and 2.

I have another numpy array like this :

```
remains_doors = [ [0,2], [0,1], [1,2], ... [1,2], [0,1],] # of size m
```

each entry of remains_doors is a list of 2 numbers between 0 and 2, the numbers cannot be the same.

I need to create a new array, called new_array, from answer and remains_doors with the following criteria:
for each set, i must keep the corresponding data who are not in answer, or if the data is not present choose a random value.
For example :

```
answer        = [1, 0, 1, 2, 1 ,0]
remains_doors = [ [0,1], [1,2], [0,1], [2,0], [1,0], [0,1]]

new_array = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

The difficulty is that for doing this i don't must use any loops (for, while).
(for your information, this is a part of the monthy hall problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use any `for` or `while` loop, maybe a recursion can fit?

```
answer        = [1, 0, 1, 2, 1 ,0]
remains_doors = [[0,1], [1,2], [0,1], [2,0], [1,0], [0,1]]
new_array = [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]

import random

def do_the_job(answer, doors, idx = 0, new_array = []):
  end = len(answer)
  if idx < 0 or idx >= end:
    return
  a = answer[idx]
  d = doors[idx]
  if a in d:
    d.remove(a)
    new_array.append(d[0])
  else: new_array.append(random.sample(d, 1)[0])
  do_the_job(answer, doors, idx + 1, new_array)
  return new_array

print(do_the_job(answer, remains_doors))
#=> [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1] or sometimes [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up documentation for the `zip` command and also search for information about list comprehensions in python.

Looking at your question for the second position you have 0 compared with [1,2], your answer for this is 2 so:

```
new_array = [max(z for z in y if z != x) for x,y in zip(answer,remains_doors)]
```

If you want [1,2] rather than just 2 then remove the `max` call.